# Help me find cos b

Tags: trigonometry

In the figure $EC=1, AE=3, BD=4, AD=2,$ $m(AED)=a$ and $m(CBD)=b.$ If $\sin a=\frac{1}{3}$ what is $\cos b$ equal to?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: I know the definitions of trigonometric functions, but I do not know how the sine function is found, and how to then assign the cosinus function

Comment: Doesn't $AC=1$ requiere $AE<1$? Perhaps it's $EC=1$?

Comment: Don't you mean $CE=1$?  From the diagram, $CA=4$.

Comment: i correct, sorry

Comment: yes, $CA=4, BA=6$, but i didnt know how to find $cos b$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triangle BAC has side-angle-side = 6-A-4

Triangle EAD has side-angle-side = 3-A-2

So these are similar triangles. So $\frac{BC}{ED} = 2$, or $|BC| = 2|ED|$

Law of sines in the small triangle says $\frac{\sin(a)}{2} = \frac{\sin(A)}{ED}$ so $ED = 2\frac{\sin(A)}{\sin(a)} = 6\sin(A)$ (since $\sin(a)$ is given to be $\frac{1}{3}$).

Law of sines in the large triangle says $\frac{\sin(A)}{BC} = \frac{\sin(b)}{4}$ so $BC = 4\frac{\sin(A)}{\sin(b)}$

But $|BC| = 2|ED|$ so $4\frac{\sin(A)}{\sin(b)} = 12\sin(A)$ and cancelling $\sin(A)$
from both sides gives $\sin(b) = \frac{1}{3}$, and so $cos(b) = \sqrt{1-\sin^2{b}} = \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{9}} = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$

Comment: JimN: thanky very much